# What Sites are offering FREE Wordpress themes that are SAFE?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm relatively new to wordpress.

I mainly use wp for very simple websites, where i just want a simple theme other than the default, and there is no need to pay for a premium theme.

Unfortunately, the words "free" and "word press theme" on google attract a host of malicious websites.

Unfortunately, the majority of free wp theme websites (that i found) have themes that contain hidden links, malware, advertising, or are stolen from other websites.

Please provide any websites that offer free wp themes that are clean, malware free and advertising free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smashing Magazine often do great themes for free - have a look at:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/wordpress/

They often do 'round up' posts of great free themes too.

Comment: +1, good answer, they have some excellent links indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is wordpress itself

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/

Comment: It isn't, they have footer links

Comment: Thanks for the anwer, but i already know about wordress.org, i was thinking about other websites :)

Comment: @mazgalici: Wordpress allow tested and approved themes to be available to download on their site and the provide the footer links which just indicate that hey this is footer link area and you can place your own link here